# CocoaAsyncSocket TCP proxy/tunnel

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, gcdasyncsocket, cocoaasyncsocket

I'm using CocoaAsyncSocket trying to create a TCP-tunnel/mux/demux, forwarding all connections through a port pair (A <-> B). 
Everything written to port A should "come out" of port B and vice versa. I can use only ports A and B, can't open other ports.

I'm creating 2 listening `AsyncSockets` on A and B and have 2 arrays of the connected clients, and in

`- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
   if (sock.localPort == B.localPort)
   {
       for (AsyncSocket * cl in clientsOfA)
       {
           [cl writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
           [cl readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
       }
       [sock readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
   }`

everything I read on port A I will send to all clients of port B and vice versa. 
On A's side there is a Safari, making requests to A.

My problem is :
When data comes back from B port, and on A's side I have 5 clients ( thank you Safari ...), I won't know which one initially requested the current data packet, so I'm sending data to all of them and...well... everything is messed up.

Can this mux/demux be achieved this way at all ? Or what is the correct way to achieve this ? How could I differentiate the initiating clients ?

Comment: Please, clarify, who sends what to whom. Esp. *On A's side there is a Safari, making requests to A* is unclear to me.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad It meant, that to port A a Safari makes requests.

Comment: Anyway, I gave up on this. It is way too complicated to implement something like this. I made only a HTTP proxy and modified some headers to know exactly which client sends which request so I can send them back the correct response.